# Regular expression does not match newline obtained from Formatter object

Tags: java, regex, formatter

I cannot match a String containing newlines when the newline is obtained by using `%n` in `Formatter` object or `String.format()`. Please have a look at the following program:

```
public class RegExTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input1 = String.format("Hallo\nnext line");
    String input2 = String.format("Hallo%nnext line");
    String pattern = ".*[\n\r].*";
    System.out.println(input1+": "+input1.matches(pattern));
    System.out.println(input2+": "+input2.matches(pattern));
  }

}
```

and its output:

```
Hallo
next line: true
Hallo
next line: false
```

What is going on here? Why doesn't the second string match?

Java version is 1.6.0_21.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can set the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag to make `.` match newlines, as default it doesn't. It is done with the `(?s)` notation. So, this regex does what you want:

```
    String pattern = "(?s).*[\n\r].*";
```

Comment: Then why does the first one match (I'm on windows)?

Comment: Also, you might want to switch the `[\r\n]` part to `\r?\n` to be able to match both `\n` and `\r\n`.

Comment: Just found out. On windows, lineend is `\r\n`. The `\n` in `input1` is not considered a line end and so the regex matches.

Comment: Thank you, but in this case it is not needed. I'm matching to find out whether field quoting is necessary while creating a csv file, and so it is sufficient to know if any of these characters are conained in the string.

Comment: The second one using `"(?m).*[\n\r].*"` doesn't work either, but `"(?s).*[\n\r].*"` does. Please update your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: First one should be "(?s).*[\n\r].*", second one doesn't work. If you update the first and remove the second, I will accept.

Comment: @Alex: Sorry for all the different answers, I had troubles understanding exactly what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't get this answer, why not just `"(?s).*"` or `"(?s).*\\R.*"` if you want there to be at least one new line?

Comment: @Axel if you're writing CSV output, you should be aware that it requires `\r\n` row terminators, regardless of the platform's line ending.

Comment: The current regex is overly verbose, and adding the `(?s)` doesn't truly "fix" the problem. The question is worded very narrowly and the actual use-case (if you read the comments) is even more narrow. So this works for this particular use-case but this answer doesn't actually explain why. There are much better ways to (a) write a regular expression to solve the original problem, (b) use regular expressions in general to solve this problem, and (c) solve the problem _without_ regular expressions.

Answer (score 22):

On Windows, in Java, `\n` is LF, `\r` is CR and `%n` is CRLF.
Your pattern does not match the latter.

As of Java 8, you can now use [`\R`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) in regular expressions to match any end-of-line sequence.

> Linebreak matcher
>
> `\R` Any Unicode linebreak sequence, is equivalent to `\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]`

Example:

```
String pattern = ".*\\R.*";
String.format("Hallo\nnext line").matches(pattern); // true
String.format("Hallo%nnext line").matches(pattern); // true
String.format("Hallo same line").matches(pattern); // false
```

Comment: Yes, ".*\r?\n.*" works, but not if there are multiple line breaks. I now am using "(?s).*[\n\r].*".

Comment: `(?s).*\\R.*` can be used if you want there to be at least one line end. Otherwise just use `(?s).*` to allow any number of line endings.

Comment: @Axel if the aim to test whether a string contains any linebreak, use the pattern `\\R` and the `Matcher.test()` method.

Comment: Ah, \R was introduced in Java 8. It wasn’t available when I posted the question, and I missed this addition to the Java regex implementation. The second thing I learned today. As that library still exists and now has a minimum Java version of 8, I will update my code right away.