# Pattern is not matching when it contains a new line

Tags: java, android, regex

Here is my code

```
 Pattern pbold = Pattern.compile(".*\\* *(.*?) *\\*.*");
 Matcher mbold = pbold.matcher(s);
 mbold.find();
```

Comment: Please give an example of the input that you are trying to match.

Comment: "*apple*" work with out new line but when take new line not working then

Comment: That regex will not match `apple`, with or without a newline.

Comment: Also look at the DOTALL option `(?s)`, so  `.`  matches newline characters as well.

Comment: stackoverflow replacing *  by italic text

Comment: Wrap it in back ticks, `\`*apple*\``.

Comment: @Andy Turner exactly , without new line it find out otherwise not

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the metacharacter that matches whitespaces charaters: `(?s)`
This whitespace metacharacter matches:

- A space character
- A tab character
- A carriage return character
- A new line character
- A vertical tab character

For more info about this special characters, please consult [The Java Tutorials - Regular Expressions - Predefined Character Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html).

The code belows matches the case you need:

```
String s = "abc021\n" +
            "34-+\n" +
            "*\n" +
            "a\n" +
            "p\n" +
            "p\n" +
            "l\n" +
            "e\n" +
            "*\n" +
            "fga32\n" +
            "49";
    Pattern pbold = Pattern.compile(".*\\* *((?s).*?) *\\*.*");
    Matcher mbold = pbold.matcher(s);
    mbold.find();
```

There is also a similar question here: 
[Regular expression does not match newline obtained from Formatter object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644100/regular-expression-does-not-match-newline-obtained-from-formatter-object)

Comment: I want `*apple*` will be became *apple*  in bold without stars .

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @AyushSaxena.
The regex above matches words between stars even across lines.
I need precise description on your **input** and **expected output** to give you better feedback.

Comment: no consequtive ** will be replace I have done this   Pattern pbold = Pattern.compile(".*\\* *(.*?) *\\*.*");

Comment: but this replace ** also to bold ** = nothing hope you understand

Comment: If I understood correctly:  
INPUT:       `I want *apple* and **orange** in bold`  
OUTPUT:   I want **apple** and **orange** in bold  
  
The problem is **Java regex does NOT support recursive patterns**; i.e. it's not possible to recognize something like `**apple**` with a variable number of stars (e.g. `***apple***`).  
  
My suggestion to simplify this regex is to match the innermost pair of stars. For example:  
INPUT:       `I want *apple* and **orange** in bold`  
OUTPUT:   I want **apple** and * **orange** * in bold

Comment: Another possibility is to extend the code that matches words/phrases to be set in bold, to match multiple stars.  
But unfortunately you have to do it manually.  
An also consider the following case:  
INPUT: `*apple* and **orange** match *fruit**`  
OUTPUT: **apple** and **orange** match **fruit** *

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112681/discussion-between-esteban-and-ayush-saxena).

Answer (score 0):

Use flags igm like below:

```
Pattern pbold = Pattern.compile(".*\\* *(.*?) *\\*.*");
 Matcher mbold = pbold.matcher(s, Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE|Pattern.DOTALL);
 mbold.find();
```

Comment: `Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` are completely redundant here. None of the tokens used in the regex is affected by these 2 flags.

Answer (score 0):

This regular  expression might solve your problem...

```
 Pattern pbold = Pattern.compile(".*\\*[ \n]*(.*?)[ \n]*\\*.*");
 Matcher mbold = pbold.matcher(s);
 mbold.find();
```

If this doesn't solve it..please elaborate what you are trying to get through this expression.