# String.matches() with \n

Tags: java

Why the `String::matches` method returns `false` when the string contains `\n`?

```
public class AppMain2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String data1 = "\n  London";    
        System.out.println(data1.matches(".*London.*")); // false
    }    
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression does not match newline obtained from Formatter object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644100/regular-expression-does-not-match-newline-obtained-from-formatter-object) http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 5):

If you want `matches` to return `true`, you need to use `(?s)` or [`Pattern.DOTALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL).

This way `.` matches any character including `\n`

```
System.out.println(data1.matches("(?s).*London.*"));
```

or:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*London.*", Pattern.DOTALL);
System.out.println(data1.matches(pattern));
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't match because "." in regex may not match line terminators as in the documentation here :

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

Answer (score 2):

By default Java's `.` does not match newlines. To have `.` include newlines, set the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag with `(?s)`:

```
System.out.println(data1.matches("(?s).*London.*"));
```

Note for those coming from other regex flavors, the Java documentation use of the term "match" is different from other languages. What is meant is Java's `string::matches()` returns true only if the *entire string* is matched, i.e. it behaves as if a `^` and `$` were added to the head and tail of the passed regex, NOT simply that it contains a match.

Answer (score -1):

**"\n"** considered as newline so **String.matches** searching for the pattern to in new line.so returning false try something like this.

> Pattern.compile(".*London.*", Pattern.MULTILINE);